# How to change the mouse cursor over an embedded flash?

Tags: html, css, flash

For changing the cursor for a custom one in HTML I add the following CSS property:

```
cursor: url(../img/koala.gif), auto;
```

I added that property this way:

```
body {

    cursor: url(../img/koala.gif), auto;
}

a:hover {

    cursor: url(../img/koala.gif), auto;
}
```

But I can't get it to work over a flash, I already tried:

```
object {
    cursor: url(../img/koala.gif), auto;
}
```

But got not results, how can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change the code in the flash object with AS (action script), I don't think you can do this with HTML/CSS (maybe JS but I think that once you move focus to the flash object by hovering over it then the flash plugin takes over). Here is some AS3 you can use -

```
mouse.cursor="ibeam"
mouse.cursor="hand"
mouse.cursor="arrow"
mouse.cursor="auto"
```

Code for custom mouse cursor -

```
function boardOver(e:MouseEvent):void {
    this.addChild(disk);
    disk.x=stage.mouseX;
    disk.y=stage.mouseY;
    Mouse.hide();
}
```

Comment: What about using a custom image cursor?

Comment: Here is a good step by step on that, basically you need to create a new sprite and have it move in the same coordinates as the mouse. http://www.flashandmath.com/howtos/cursor/